# Finding the Ultimate manager ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

The Problem Description:

I need to find the Ultimate Manager's Name (or ID) from a Given table for a Particular ID.
That is,For eg let:

```
3 has manager ID 4
4 has manager id 5,
5 has manager ID 109
```

So if I give cemp_id 3 I should get manager ID 109.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMERID       AS ChildId, 
       P.CUSTOMERID       AS ParentId, 
       P.PARENTCUSTOMERID AS GrantParentId, 
       C.CUSTOMERNAME 
FROM   CUSTOMER_PROFILE C 
       JOIN CUSTOMER_PROFILE P 
         ON C.PARENTCUSTOMERID = P.CUSTOMERID
```

but this only works on 2 levels of hierarchy and I need it for N levels of hierarchy.

Comment: Please describe your db structure and specify the sql dialect.

Comment: You'll need to explain your schema and data is more detail or await the answer of a (lucky) telepath. Showing some SQL that you think might work or shows your attempts might help.

Comment: A recursive CTE could solve your problem, but as others have mentioned, we need to know at the very least what RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work with SQL Server 2008 or higher:

```
declare @id int = 1

;with cte
as
(
    select PARENTCUSTOMERID, 0 as level 
    from CUSTOMER_PROFILE where CUSTOMERID = @id

    union all

    select t.PARENTCUSTOMERID, cte.level  + 1 as level
    from CUSTOMER_PROFILE t
    inner join cte on t.CUSTOMERID = cte.PARENTCUSTOMERID 

)

select top 1 PARENTCUSTOMERID from cte
order by level desc
```

Comment: Can we perform this without recursion? Example, I am working on Redshift. How will I be able to do this?

Comment: I'm speaking from memory but as Redshift uses postgresql, it should be supported.

Comment: No, RS doesn't support such queries as of now: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html